# Proof fraction with sum of numerators and denominators is larger than the minimum of the individual fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For my research, I am dealing with the following hypothesis:

$\frac{x_1+x_2}{d_1+d_2} \geq \min \left(\frac{x_1}{d_1}, \frac{x_2}{d_2}\right)$

with the following assumptions

- $x_1,x_2,d_1,d_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ with $d_1+d_2 \geq 1$
- $0 \leq \frac{x_1+x_2}{d_1+d_2} \leq 1$

As for the proof, I did not get any further than below:

Let's assume that $\min \left(\frac{x_1}{d_1}, \frac{x_2}{d_2}\right) = \frac{x_1}{d_1}$, then

$\frac{x_1+x_2}{d_1+d_2} \geq \min \left(\frac{x_1}{d_1}, \frac{x_2}{d_2}\right) = \frac{x_1}{d_1}$

Multiplying both sides with the denominator gives us

$d_1(x_1+x_2) \geq x_1(d_1+d_2)$

Dividing both sides with the shorter terms gives us

$\frac{x_1+x_2}{x_1} \geq \frac{d_1+d_2}{d_1}$

Any suggestions for how I could proceed are much appreciated!

Comment: Are $x_1, x_2, d_1, d_2$ real numbers? Integers? Positive integers?

Comment: You tagged the question "solution-verification", but I don't see any solution to verify.

Comment: @jjagmath apologies! I added this information now. I added the tag because I read in the description that you could also use the tag for "suggestions on improvements of the proof". I agree I do not have a proof yet, so any suggestion is welcome here :).

Comment: Here's a hint: assume $\frac{x_1}{d_1} \le \frac{x_2}{d_2}$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that this post is tagged with calculus? PS jjagmath's solution works

Comment: @Hersh it is my first time posting here, was not really sure about the tags. Looks like I chose the wrong ones :P.

Comment: @jjagmath I'm glad to read that it is provable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the stated assumptions can be dropped; $x_1, x_2, d_1, d_2$ can be any real numbers with $d_1 > 0,$ $d_2 > 0.$

Let
$$
\alpha = \min\left\{\frac{x_1}{d_1}, \frac{x_2}{d_2}\right\}.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{x_1}{d_1} \geqslant \alpha, \
\frac{x_2}{d_2} \geqslant \alpha.
$$
But $d_1 > 0$ and $d_2 > 0,$ therefore
$$
x_1 \geqslant \alpha d_1, \
x_2 \geqslant \alpha d_2.
$$
Therefore
$$
x_1 + x_2 \geqslant \alpha d_1 + \alpha d_2 = \alpha(d_1 + d_2).
$$
But $d_1 + d_2 > 0,$ therefore
$$
\frac{x_1 + x_2}{d_1 + d_2} \geqslant \alpha  =
\min\left\{\frac{x_1}{d_1}, \frac{x_2}{d_2}\right\}. \quad \square
$$

Answer (score 1):

So assume $\frac {x_1}{d_1}\le \frac {x_2}{d_2}$.  As wall are positive that is true if and only if $x_1d_2 \le x_2d_1$.

So how does $\frac {x_1+x_2}{d_1+d_2}$ compare to $\frac {x_i}{d_i}$.

Let's use $???$ to mean $\le$ or $\ge$ but we don't know which but every step is an if and only iff.  In other words, lets "solve for ????".  Or maybe I should call this a "work backwords" proof.

(WARNING!!!!! "work backwards" proofs only work if every step is "if and only if" or "only if".  The *fail* if *any* step is an actual "if ... then" step.  Because we are working backward our steps need to all be "we can only get then .... if....".)

$\frac {x_1+x_2}{d_1+d_2} ??? \frac {x_i}{d_i} \iff$

$x_1d_i + x_2d_i ??? x_id_1 + x_id_2$

If $i = 1$ we get

$x_1d_1 + x_2d_1 ???? x_1d1 + x_1d_2$

$x_2d_1 ??? x_1d_2$.

As $x_2d_1 \ge x_1d_2$ we have $\frac {x_1+x_2}{d_1+d_2} \ge \frac {x_1}{d_1}=\min(\frac {x_i}{d_i})$.

ANd if $i=2$ we get by the exact same argument

$x_1d_2 + x_2d_2 ???? x_2d1 + x_2d_2$

$x_1d_2 ??? x_2d_1$.

As $x_1d_2 \le x_2d_1$ we have $\frac {x_1+x_2}{d_1+d_2} \le \frac {x_2}{d_2}=\max(\frac {x_i}{d_i})$.

=====

If you don't like that we can work forward (now that we can see where the secret step came from:

$\frac {x_1}{d_1}\le \frac {x_2}{d_2}$

$x_1d_2 \le x_2d_1$

$x_1d_1 + x_1d_2 \le x_1d_1 + x_2d_1$  (this was the secret step)

$x_1(d_1 + d_2) \le d_1(x_1 + x_2)$

$\frac {x_1}{d_1} \le \frac {x_1+x_2}{d_1+d_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have for positive real numbers:

\begin{align}
&\frac{a}{b}\le \frac{a+c}{b+d}\\
\iff\\
&a(b+d) \le b(a+c)\\
\iff\\
&a b+a d \le ba + bc\\
\iff\\
&ad \le b c\\
\iff\\
&\frac{a}{b} \le \frac{c}{d}
\end{align}